# Clone form rows in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mj1X.jpg) like this and I have to code it with symfony2 FormBuilder I tried something like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name',CheckboxType::class
        )->add('quant', TextType::class,array()
        )
    ->getForm();
```

and i create array with data and in view i use:

```
{% for part in parts %}
  {{ form_widget(Form.name,{ 'label': part.name,'value':part.id, 'checked' :part.checked}) }}
  {{ form_widget(Form.quant,{ 'label': 'Quantity','value': part.quant }) }}

            {% endfor %}
```

and it's work but i get only first row and others aren't display.

How can i make form like this in symfony2?

Comment: You want to take a good look on chapter in symfony cookbook regarding embedding a collection of forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [collection form type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection):

```php
// ...
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('quantity', IntegerType::class);
    }
}
```

```php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('name', CheckboxType::class)
    ->add('products', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => ProductType::class,
    ])
    ->getForm();
```

For more information, see also the documentation referenced by @MiroDavid in the comments: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: so if i have form_row like:
 [checkbox] [input type=text] [select] 

i have to create three *Type Class for each input in row?

Comment: @goq123 no, if each entry (product) needs these 3 fields, add these fields to the `ProductType::buildForm()` method.

Comment: but i don't have field in database which is a checkbox value, checkbox is only to tell me - this product has to be save